# include/require not working PHP

Tags: php, mysql, include

I want to include a file that is located in the working folder of my project, called `Proj`. This folder includes all files of the project including the `index.html` and it's path is:

> /var/www/html/Proj

I've tried many ways of doing this, unsucessfully:

```
include 'Clockwork.php';

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."Clockwork.php");
```

By the way, the output of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is

> /var/www/html/

I tried `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Proj/Clockwork.php");` but that didn't work either.

The error I'm getting is :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Clockwork' not found in (location of php php file that is trying to include the file) Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in etc etc
```

If it helps, my `php.ini` file by default is set up as...

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path
```

This is strange and I'm don't know what else to do.

Clockwork is an API from https://www.clockworksms.com/doc/easy-stuff/code-wrappers/php/

It's a long file. The heading starts like :

```
<?php
/**
* Clockwork PHP API
*
* @package     Clockwork
* @copyright   Mediaburst Ltd 2015
* @license     MIT
* @link        http://www.clockworksms.com
* @version     1.3.2
*/

namespace mediaburst\ClockworkSMS;

/**
* Main Clockwork API Class
*
* @package     Clockwork
* @since       1.0
*/
class Clockwork {

  /*
  * Version of this class
  */
  const VERSION           = '2.0.0';
 //....
}
```

Comment: You need to define 'not working' before anybody can help you. What are you expecting? What are you getting? What error messages do you see?

Comment: I'm testing from the cloud server hence it does not display the error (just says This page isn’t working
165.227.177.227 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500). I tested from localhost. I edited the post to show the error it gives

Comment: @codEinsteinn, then your error is actually in Clockwork.php.  It references a class that doesn't exist.  Can you post the contents of Clockwork.php?

Comment: I've posted some of  the heading of the file. Clockworks.php is an API. The source is https://www.clockworksms.com/doc/easy-stuff/code-wrappers/php/

Comment: The file is being read successfully but there is an error in it. You can use `php -l Clockwork.php` to run a lint check for syntax errors, but I suspect that your PHP version is older that what this code requires.

Comment: Alex, where do I run that command? From putty.exe?

Comment: Yes. (Or any similar shell prompt.) Make sure you specify the full path to the file if you're not located in the directory.

Comment: Alex, it says "no syntax errors detected in var/www/Proj/Clockwork.php"

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.. I was in fact using an deprecated way of creating a new Clockwork object. it's working now

Answer (score 0):

try `require_once()` with your file path;

Comment: hi Ozal, i did require_once("var/www/html/Proj/Clockwork.php"); but  that did not work :(

Comment: What @Ozal was telling you was that using "require_once()" as opposed to "include_once()" is require will cause a fatal error, and will give us more to go on as to why it's not loading.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if it's located in the same directory, you could use:

```
include_once(__DIR__."/Clockwork.php");
```

Comment: Then the above should work.  I would do `require_once(__DIR__."/Clockwork.php");`, and then post the results here.

Comment: it didn't. It shows "This page isn’t working
165.227.177.227 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: your solution works fine. The file was being recognized but I was not creating the Clockwork object correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try added a "/" include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Clockwork.php");
That might be the answer to your problem.